# Python plotly | disable ALL rangesliders in a figure that has subplots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Using plotly(dash) I add multiple subplots to a figure using figure.add_candlestick(**args)

After the loop is done I disable the xaxis_rangeslider_visible but I still have a rangeslider at the bottom of the second/last chart. Does anyone know how to hide ALL rangeslider in a figure with multiple plots?

```
PositionFig = PositionFig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False,
                          title_text="Position Charts",
                          height=1000)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: you can avoid the loop with `fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=False)` or in your case:

```py
PositionFig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=False)
```

Or you can loop back through and set it off for each axis:

```py
for i in range(number_of_subplots,0,-1): # starting with the last and stopping at 0
    PositionFig.update_xaxes(row=i, col=1, rangeslider_visible=False)
```

where `number_of_subplots` is how many subplots you have, and assuming that they are in a single column.

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed it after posting this thread by using a loop

But the update_xaxes() is a way better method. Thank you a ton for this